# Reuse results of first computation in second computation

Tags: java, apache-flink

I'm trying to write a computation in Flink which requires two phases.

In the first phase I start from a text file, and perform some parameter estimation, obtaining as a result a Java object representing a statistical model of the data.

In the second phase, I'd like to use this object to generate data for a simulation.

I'm unsure how to do this. I tried with a `LocalCollectionOutputFormat`, and it works locally, but when I deploy the job on a cluster, I get a `NullPointerException` - which is not really surprising.

What is the Flink way of doing this?

Here is my code:

```
ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
GlobalConfiguration.includeConfiguration(configuration);

// Phase 1: read file and estimate model
DataSource<Tuple4<String, String, String, String>> source = env
        .readCsvFile(args[0])
        .types(String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class);

List<Tuple4<Bayes, Bayes, Bayes, Bayes>> bayesResult = new ArrayList<>();
// Processing here...
....output(new LocalCollectionOutputFormat<>(bayesResult));

env.execute("Bayes");

DataSet<BTP> btp = env
        .createInput(new BayesInputFormat(bayesResult.get(0)))
// Phase 2: BayesInputFormat generates data for further calculations
// ....
```

This is the exception I get:

```
Error: The program execution failed: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.LocalCollectionOutputFormat.close(LocalCollectionOutputFormat.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSinkTask.invoke(DataSinkTask.java:176)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.RuntimeEnvironment.run(RuntimeEnvironment.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.io.LocalCollectionOutputFormat.close(LocalCollectionOutputFormat.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSinkTask.invoke(DataSinkTask.java:176)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.RuntimeEnvironment.run(RuntimeEnvironment.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.run(Client.java:328)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.run(Client.java:294)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.run(Client.java:288)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:55)
    at it.list.flink.test.Test01.main(Test01.java:62)
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the latest release (0.9-milestone-1) a `collect()` method was added to Flink

```
public List<T> collect()
```

which fetches a `DataSet<T>` as `List<T>` to the driver program. `collect()` will also trigger an immediate execution of the program (don't need to call `ExecutionEnvironment.execute()`). Right now, there is size limitation for data sets of about 10 MB.

If you do not evaluate the models in the driver program, you can also chain both programs together and emit the model to the side by attaching a data sink. This will be more efficient, because the data won't do the round-trip over the client machine.

Comment: Thanks, that's quite useful. I tried chaining, but the result of the first run is basically a set of parameters, that is a single row. Distributing this row to the clients, I can generate data in parallel on each client with InputFormat, while with chaining I could not find a way to do the same.

Comment: Not sure if I got it right, but you could maybe the following trick would work as well:

Comment: Put the parameters into a broadcast variable and distribute it to a set of `flatMap` operators. Each of these `flatMap` operators will have access to all parameters and can emit as many records as you like. However, you need to trigger the execution of the `flatMaps` with a dummy input record, which could be served from a collection input format containing one `Integer` for each parallel `flatMap` instance. The data of the collection IF needs to be `rebalanced` before going into the `flatMap` operators.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flink prior to 0.9 you may use the following snippet to collect your dataset to a local collection:

```
val dataJavaList = new ArrayList[K]
val outputFormat = new LocalCollectionOutputFormat[K](dataJavaList)
dataset.output(outputFormat)
env.execute("collect()")
```

Where `K` is the type of object you want to collect

Comment: I don't know Scala, but it seems to me that what you are suggesting is equal to what I reported in my question, and with this approach I get a NPE.